# How to write my own collection in qt?

Tags: c++, qt, collections, foreach

I'm writing some class which will act like a usual collection in QT:

```
class MyCollection
{
  MyElement & at(int) const;
  MyElement & operator[](int) const;
  int count() const;
};
```

Now I want to enumerate all elements in my new class with QT's foreach. What should I do to achieve this?

Comment: You should look at the source of some of the container classes in Qt. See [QVector](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/blobs/4.8/src/corelib/tools/qvector.h), for example.

Comment: Read the Q_FOREACH macro, Add iterators, begin, end, operator++ etc. until it compiles. In doubt, follow STL container design guidelines rather than Qt-specific, that makes the container more generically usable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Qt (4.8 at least) uses (from `foreach` macro) a template wrapper class `QForeachContainer` (see `qglobal.h`) to iterate over *smth*. Default implementation calls `begin()`/`end()`, but you can write your own specialization as well... or just implement `iterator begin()`, `iterator end()` members

Comment: Same as in STL? Is there any complete guide?